# Pandas - Sum by week, using a date range in each record

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following data sample:

| Hours Per Work Week | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31 |
| 20 | 2021-08-15 | 2021-09-15 |
| 40 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-30 |

I need to get a total by week distribution so the expected dataframe would be something:

|  | total_hours |
| --- | --- |
| week |  |
| 2021-08-01 | 30 |
| 2021-08-08 | 30 |
| 2021-08-15 | 30 |
| 2021-08-22 | 30 |
| 2021-08-29 | 30 |
| 2021-09-05 | 60 |
| 2021-09-12 | 60 |
| 2021-09-19 | 40 |
| 2021-09-26 | 40 |

I get how to get the index for weeks:

```
all_dates = pd.date_range('2021-08-01', '2021-09-30', freq='W')
```

but then how to use the weeks to sum from the dataset that fits in the range I'm not sure.

Thank you!!

Comment: Look into groupby and grouper. You need to do something like: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Start Date", freq="1W"))["hours"].sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
weeks = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start Date'], x['End Date'], freq='W'),
                 axis='columns').explode().rename('week')

out = df[['Hours Per Work Week']].join(weeks).groupby('week').sum()
```

```
>>> weeks
            Hours Per Work Week
week
2021-08-01                   50
2021-08-08                   50
2021-08-15                   70
2021-08-22                   70
2021-08-29                   70
2021-09-05                   60
2021-09-12                   60
2021-09-19                   40
2021-09-26                   40
```